# Is it possible to get both objects when doing query time joing in Lucene

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I have one index for products, and one index for prices.

Let's say the documents in products index has: `Id, Name, CategoryId` fields
and in the prices index has: `Id, ProductId, Amount` fields.

A product can have multiple prices. 
I need to get the product with all of its prices when doing a search in Lucene

I search for products on CategoryId. 
The query below returns all the prices, but I need to have the product as well.

```cs
var fromField = "Id";
var toField = "ProductId";
var categoryId = 2462;

var fromQuery = new BooleanQuery();
fromQuery.Add(NumericRangeQuery.NewInt32Range("CategoryId", categoryId, categoryId, true, true), Occur.MUST);

var joinQuery = JoinUtil.CreateJoinQuery(fromField, false, toField, fromQuery, _indexProductSearcher, ScoreMode.None);

var topDocs = _indexPriceSearcher.Search(joinQuery, 1800);
foreach (var scoreDoc in topDocs.ScoreDocs)
{
   var foundPrice = _indexPriceSearcher.Doc(scoreDoc.Doc);
}
```

I could search for prices, get all the results, and for each product search for prices and build the response. 
But I was wondering if there is something built in for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be interested to see if someone comes up with something built in.  I can't think of a way to achieve your goal other than to do it manually.  Manual way: You could do it in two queries one that reads in all the products for a category, and one query that reads in all the prices for the products you just obtained in the first query.  Then you can match up the prices with the products using these two lists. Just a thought.  Sorry I don't have something better for you.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was thinking as well. I was hoping there is something more optimized than this, but alas.

Answer (score 0):

After some testings, I found that making a new price search for each product is quite wasteful, and takes a lot of time.

The solution for us is to use `JoinUtil.CreateJoinQuery`. So something like this:

```
var fromQuery = new BooleanQuery();
fromQuery.Add(NumericRangeQuery.NewInt32Range("CategoryIds", categoryId, categoryId, true, true), Occur.MUST);

var joinQuery = JoinUtil.CreateJoinQuery(fromField, false, toField, fromQuery, _indexProductSearcher, ScoreMode.None);

var topDocs = _indexPriceSearcher.Search(joinQuery, int.MaxValue);
```

Here we get all the prices in a category, and then can cretate a `Lookup` on the `ProductId`, and assign the prices to each product.